# Question about removing direct reference to Delegate Class and ViewController in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am making a SignUp screen. I connected 4 TextFields as @IBOutlet Collection to the ViewController. And I created a separate TextFieldDelegate class that manages UITextFieldDelegate. The problem here is that the TextFieldDelegate is directly referencing the ViewController to access the TextField Collection.

**TextFieldDelegate.swift**

```
class TextFieldDelegate: NSObject, UITextFieldDelegate {
    private weak var signUpViewController: SignUpViewController?
    
    init(_ signUpViewController: SignUpViewController) {
        self.signUpViewController = signUpViewController
    }
    
    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        textField.layer.borderWidth = 1
        textField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.systemBlue.cgColor
    }
    
    func textFieldDidChangeSelection(_ textField: UITextField) {
        guard let index = self.signUpViewController?.signUpTextFields.firstIndex(of: textField) else { return }
        guard let validatable = self.signUpViewController?.mapping(by: index) else { return }
}
```

**SignUpViewController.swift**

```
class SignUpViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet var signUpTextFields: [UITextField]! {
        didSet {
            signUpTextFields.forEach { textField in
                textField.delegate = textFieldDelegate
                textField.returnKeyType = .next
            }
        }
    }

    private lazy var textFieldDelegate = TextFieldDelegate(self)
}
```

**Problem Code**

```
private weak var signUpViewController: SignUpViewController?
    
init(_ signUpViewController: SignUpViewController) {
    self.signUpViewController = signUpViewController
}
```

The code in this problem is where the TextFieldDelegate refers directly to the ViewController. Is there a way to access the ViewController by other than direct reference to this code? If not, should I write code in ViewController that needs to access SignUpViewController?

Comment: Why is directly accessing `SignUpViewController` a "problem"? Tight coupling?

Comment: Yes! tight coupling

Comment: To decouple this, we really need to know what you are doing in `textFieldDidChangeSelection`. If what you are doing really _is_ something that's very closely related to `SignUpViewController`, then I don't think it should be decoupled.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a 'Swift question' in particular, but a general question of Software design. I totally get why you consider this to be an issue, though.

You could replace the direct reference by using Events or several Observables, for example by using RxSwift. Your `SignUpViewController` then simply subscribes to the events your `TextFieldDelegate` fires.

```swift
import Foundation
import UIKit
import RxSwift

class TextFieldDelegate: NSObject, UITextFieldDelegate {
    
    private let _didChangeSelection = PublishSubject<UITextField>()
    
    func textFieldDidChangeSelection(_ textField: UITextField) {
        _didChangeSelection.onNext(textField)
    }
    
    var didChangeSelection: Observable<UITextField> {
        return _didChangeSelection
    }
    
}

class SignUpViewController: UIViewController {
    
    //[...]
    private let disposables = DisposeBag()
    
    private func initSubscriptions() {
        Observable.merge(
            signupTextFields.compactMap {
                $0.delegate as? TextFieldDelegate
            }.map {
                $0.didChangeSelection
            }
        ).subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] textField in
            guard let index = self?.signUpTextFields.firstIndex(of: textField) else { return }
            guard let validatable = self?.mapping(by: index) else { return }
            //Your subscription code
        }).disposed(by: disposables)
    }
    
}
```